# bootstrap spaceing issue during display of multicolumn texts

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code below, but i am having problem with the spacing. I am using bootstrap.  How can i have the title  and  the value eg " Leonard Moonsoooon". be only 20 px away all the time ?

How can I reduce the spacing?
Senior Advisor                 Leonard Moonsoooon

Here is my code below and fiddle
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mj3f75gg/4/)

```
  <div id="clientData">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2  col-xs-6 col-md-2OW">
                     <div class="name"><strong>Senior Advisor </strong></div>
                     <!--<div class="account"><strong> Prod </strong></div>
                   <!--  <div class="approved"><strong> Prod </strong></div>
                     <div class="activity"><strong> Last Activity </strong></div>
                     <div class="activity"rong> Risk Category</strong></div> -->
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                     <div class="name">Leonard Moonsoooon</div>
                     <!--<div class="account">0789</div>
                     <!--<div class="approved">12/5/2015</div>
                     <div class="activity">4/1/2016</div>
                     <div class="riskcategory">
                        <div style="background:Yellow; padding:2px;height:18px; width:50px;"></div>
                     </div>--->
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 col-md-2OW12 thirdrdcolTitle">
                     <div class="brokerage"><strong> Company </strong></div>
                     <!--<div class="approved"><strong> Max Approved Loan Amt </strong></div>
                     <div class="balance"><strong> Loan Balance </strong></div>
                     <div class="credit"><strong> Available Credit </strong></div>
                     <div class="aging"><strong> Days in this Category </strong></div>  -->
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                     <div class="pledged "> YUMark</div>
                     <!--<div class="approved "> $2,050,877.82</div>
                     <div class="balance "> $1,849,000.00</div>
                     <div class="credit "> $201,877.82</div>
                     <div class="aging "> 3</div>-->
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-6">                   
                        <div class="account"><strong> Production </strong></div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="pledged "> 2351</div>

                  </div>  
               </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some really funky html going on there. However, the easiest thing you can do is just place both values into one column `div`, instead of two.

```css
.name strong{margin: 0 20px 0 0;}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4  col-xs-12 col-md-2OW">
  <div class="name"><strong>Senior Advisor</strong> Leonard Moonsoooon</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pwku8qam/